# uninitialized constant Page::PagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following routes

```
namespace :page do
  match '/about' => 'pages#show', slug: 'page_about'
  match '/contact' => 'pages#show', slug: 'page_contact'
end
```

In development and staging, going to page/about goes to the correct page.  However in production, I get an `uninitialized constant Page::PagesController` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error happens when you only have a PagesController. using namespace in routes expects you to have, using your case, Page::PagesController. Change your routes to

```
match '/page/about' => 'pages#show', slug: 'page_about'
match '/page/contact' => 'pages#show', slug: 'page_contact'
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using namespace here, and I've no idea why you're passing a "slug". For simple routes like this, all you need is this:

```
get "/page/about"
get "/page/contact"
```

These produce the following from `rake routes`:

```
pages_about   GET /pages/about(.:format)      pages#about
pages_contact GET /pages/contact(.:format)    pages#contact
```

Comment: yep i know that about rake routes. i was trying to figure out why i got that error instead so @jvnill has the better answer